# Conforming to an Obj-C protocol's property in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm implementing a protocol from an Obj-C library in a Swift class that defines two properties as:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isLoading) BOOL loading;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIExpansionStyle expansionStyle;
```

Although I'm not sure how to conform to these requirements in my Swift class.

I've looked at the Obj-C examples, but I haven't gleaned any solutions from that. I've tried declaring class variables with the same name, but that hasn't worked. Any suggestions on how I would go about this?

PS, the library in question is https://github.com/OliverLetterer/SLExpandableTableView

Comment: Have Swift code you can post? Have you declared protocol conformance in class declaration (`class myClass: Superclass, Protocol {//class code here}`)? Do you have bridging header to import the SLExpandableTableView.h as an Obj-C module Swift can see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making this harder than it needs to be. With a protocol defined like this:

```
@protocol MyProtocol

@property (nonatomic, assign, getter = isLoading) BOOL loading;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIExpansionStyle expansionStyle;

@end
```

the following class conforms:

```
class Conformer : MyProtocol {
    var loading: Bool
    var expansionStyle: UIExpansionStyle

    init(loading: Bool, expansionStyle: UIExpansionStyle) {
        self.loading = loading
        self.expansionStyle = expansionStyle
    }
}
```

Prefixing boolean getters with `is` is a Cocoa convention, so Swift already knows about it and doesn't require you to do anything special on the swift side.

The confusing part might be all the modifiers to the Objective C property declaration. Let's go through them one by one.

`nonatomic` has no equivalent in Swift, nothing to do here.

`assign` is automatic for value types, nothing to do here either.

`getter = isLoading` is a Cocoa convention which Swift understands and needs nothing from you in order to make this work.

`readonly` you *can* do this in Swift (just use the `get{ }` syntax) but it is not necessary. This is because you are allowed to expand on the contract made by the protocol. `MyProtocol` requires there be a property called `expansionStyle` that can be read from, it does *NOT* say that it must not be possible to write to that property in the type that implements the protocol, just like it doesn't say you can't have other properties/methods on that same class.

Comment: Thanks so much for the modifier explanation, that's very helpful. I had exactly this except for the init call. I had their declarations force unwrapped (var loading: Bool!) which appears to have caused the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Lance's answer didn't work for me, this is how I got isLoading to conform to the protocol (Swift 2.2)

```
var expansionStyle: UIExpansionStyle = UIExpansionStyle(0)

var _loading: Bool = false
var loading:Bool {
    @objc(isLoading) get {
        return self._loading
    }
    set(newValue){
        _loading = newValue
    }
}
```